# Is Variable size in C compiler dependent?

Tags: c, gcc, parameters, mingw

Considering the following code:

```
void print(int arr[])
{
  int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  printf("\nSize is  %d",n);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    print(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

- When the above code is compiled in GCC 6.3 or a lesser version, The output is :
  `size is 2`.
- When the code is compiled in MinGW compiler, the output is `Size is 1`

Now to the contrary, we used to study that when an array is passed as an argument, it only passes the base address of the array(*which is 4 bytes for an implicit pointer variable and integer variable both*).

Are the variable sizes compiler dependent, or I am missing something here? Please correct me

Comment: `arr[]` is a point.  `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` is size of a pointer/size of of an `int`.  No arrays involved.

Comment: In practice in C, every function taking an array should be given the size of that array, often thru some other argument

Comment: size of `int` depends on the compiler, but compiler may theoretically change it based on target platform, CPU or compiler switches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr[]`, as a function parameter, is a pointer.  `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` is the size of a pointer/size of of an `int`.  No arrays involved.

> Is Variable size in C compiler dependent?

Yes, an `int` could be 32-bit, 16-bit, etc.<sup>1</sup> (Must be at least 16)

An object pointer could be 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, or etc.<sup>1</sup> (Must be at least 16)

A pointer is often wider than an `int`, yet could be the same or (rarely) less.  The ratio could be 2/1 or 1/1 or others.

---

<sup>1</sup> Other sizes are possible and have been employed such as 36-bit `int` or 48-bit object pointer.  This is C's ability to adopt to just about any processor ever built and likely to all new ones.  The flexibility comes at the expense that *portable* code must account for these variations.

Comment: The question mentioned above was on a code competition platform which follows GCC 6.3. So, i think it would be better to preassume that similar platform will follow th 2:1 ration?

Comment: @mustangDC A reasonable [assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164078/is-variable-size-in-c-compiler-dependent/52164274?noredirect=1#comment91278798_52164274), although robust code does not rely on that 2:1 ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sizes of types are implementation-dependent. In particular, the size of a pointer to `int` and the size of an `int` are dependent on the C implementation (primarily a compiler) and may be different from each other.

The assertion in the question contained in “the base address of the array(*which is 4 bytes for an implicit pointer variable and integer variable both*)” is false, in general. It is true in some C implementations but is false in others.

The code `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` inside a function declared with `void print(int arr[])` prints the size of a pointer to `int` divided by the size of an `int`.

While C implementations are heavily influenced by the architectures and the operating systems they target, they may choose the sizes of their types for reasons other than execution speed, such as goals of supporting smaller memory use, supporting code that was not written to be fully portable to any type sizes, or supporting easier use of big integers.

Answer (score 0):

`Are the variable sizes compiler dependent ?` Yes it depends on the compiler but that doesn't mean architecture point of view is irrelevant  . Also it depends on architecture whether it's `16/32/64` bit system for e.g, in `16-bit` machines, `sizeof (int)` is `2` bytes, in `32-bit` machines it's of  `4` bytes.

It has been considered `int` was the native size of a processor, i.e., the size of register.

Here in function argument `arr[]` is a pointer not an array.

So if system is `32` bit system then

`sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`

Will result in `1` as `4/4 = 1`.

I find @Eric comments very true & interesting about compiler and architecture role in defining variable size.

> The sizes of types are ultimately determined by the C implementation
>   (notably the compiler), not the architecture or the operating system.
>   While C implementations are usually heavily influenced by the
>   architecture, computers are effectively Universal Turing Machines, so
>   that any desired choices for sizes can be implemented. C
>   implementations sometimes choose sizes based on considerations of what
>   source code is to be supported rather than what is most efficient for
>   the architecture. They may even support a choice of sizes via
>   command-line switches.

Comment: The sizes of types are ultimately determined by the C implementation (notably the compiler), not the architecture or the operating system. While C implementations are usually heavily influenced by the architecture, computers are effectively Universal Turing Machines, so that any desired choices for sizes can be implemented. C implementations sometimes choose sizes based on considerations of what source code is to be supported rather than what is most efficient for the architecture. They may even support a choice of sizes via command-line switches.

Comment: Agree Eric. Thanks for sharing that.